# How to guarantee the behavior of Set.removeAll with different type of sets?

Tags: java, collections, set, removeall

I have a problem with the HashSet and TreeSet manipulation.
Here is a simple JUnit 4 test explaining my problem :

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TreeSetTest<T> {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        final HashSet<Object> set1 = new HashSet<>();
        final TreeSet<Object> set2 = new TreeSet<>((a, b) -> a.toString().compareTo(b.toString()));
        Assert.assertEquals(0, set1.size()); // OK
        Assert.assertEquals(0, set2.size()); // OK
        set1.add(new AtomicReference<>("A"));
        set1.add(new AtomicReference<>("B"));
        set1.add(new AtomicReference<>("C"));
        Assert.assertEquals(3, set1.size()); // OK
        Assert.assertEquals(0, set2.size()); // OK
        set1.removeAll(set2);
        Assert.assertEquals(3, set1.size()); // OK
        Assert.assertEquals(0, set2.size()); // OK
        set2.add(new AtomicReference<>("A"));
        set1.removeAll(set2);
        Assert.assertEquals(3, set1.size()); // OK Nothing has been removed
        Assert.assertEquals(1, set2.size());
        set2.add(new AtomicReference<>("B"));
        set1.removeAll(set2);
        Assert.assertEquals(3, set1.size()); // OK Nothing has been removed
        Assert.assertEquals(2, set2.size());
        set2.add(new AtomicReference<>("C"));
        set1.removeAll(set2);
        Assert.assertEquals(3, set1.size()); // Error Everything has been removed and size is now 0
        Assert.assertEquals(3, set2.size());
    }

}
```

When removing all elements of `set2` from `set1`, I'm expecting to use the equality comparator of `set1` which is the case as long as `set2` has a size less than the one of `set1` but if the size of `set2` is greater or equals to the size of `set1`, the comparison is made from the `set2`.

This is very bad for me because it makes the program unpredictable.

I think it can be considered as a bug in the java implementation but my concern is:
How can I guarantee the expected behavior without rewritting eveything?

**Edit 1 after @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner comment:**

AtomicReference was just for providing a simple example. In fact, I am using a class which is final from a library so I cannot improve it easily.
But even considering a valid class implementing correctly `hashCode` and `equals`, my problem remains. Consider this now :

```
package fr.ncenerar.so;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TreeSetTest<T> {

    public static class MyObj {
        private final int value1;
        private final int value2;

        public MyObj(final int v1, final int v2) {
            super();
            this.value1 = v1;
            this.value2 = v2;
        }

        public int getValue1() {
            return this.value1;
        }

        public int getValue2() {
            return this.value2;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + this.value1;
            result = prime * result + this.value2;
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
            if (this == obj) {
                return true;
            }
            if (obj == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (this.getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
                return false;
            }
            final MyObj other = (MyObj) obj;
            if (this.value1 != other.value1) {
                return false;
            }
            if (this.value2 != other.value2) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        final HashSet<MyObj> set1 = new HashSet<>();
        final TreeSet<MyObj> set2 = new TreeSet<>((a, b) -> a.getValue1() - b.getValue1());
        Assert.assertEquals(0, set1.size()); // OK
        Assert.assertEquals(0, set2.size()); // OK
        set1.add(new MyObj(0, 0));
        set1.add(new MyObj(1, 1));
        set1.add(new MyObj(2, 2));
        Assert.assertEquals(3, set1.size()); // OK
        Assert.assertEquals(0, set2.size()); // OK
        set1.removeAll(set2);
        Assert.assertEquals(3, set1.size()); // OK
        Assert.assertEquals(0, set2.size()); // OK
        set2.add(new MyObj(0, 1));
        set1.removeAll(set2);
        Assert.assertEquals(3, set1.size()); // OK Nothing has been removed
        Assert.assertEquals(1, set2.size());
        set2.add(new MyObj(1, 2));
        set1.removeAll(set2);
        Assert.assertEquals(3, set1.size()); // OK Nothing has been removed
        Assert.assertEquals(2, set2.size());
        set2.add(new MyObj(2, 3));
        set1.removeAll(set2);
        Assert.assertEquals(3, set1.size()); // Error Everything has been removed
        Assert.assertEquals(3, set2.size());
    }

}
```

The problem is still there and `MyObj` implementation is correct. The problem comes from the fact that I am using the objects from two differents aspects. In one set, I want to keep one instance of each objects based on their equality (as in `equals` method of the object) and in another set, I want a subset of the first set in which for each `value1`, I want to keep only the firstly inserted element.

Using a `TreeSet` seemed valid.

**Edit 2:**

My bad, I missed that part of the `TreeSet` documentation:

> Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an
>   explicit comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if it
>   is to correctly implement the Set interface. (See Comparable or
>   Comparator for a precise definition of consistent withequals.) This is
>   so because the Set interface is defined interms of the equals
>   operation, but a TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons
>   using its compareTo (or compare) method, so two elements that are
>   deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal.
>   The behavior of a set is well-defined even if its ordering is
>   inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of
>   the Set interface.

If I understand correctly, I can use a `TreeSet` for my purpose but can't expect it to behave like I want it to.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Thank you for your comment. I updated my question to add some info.

Comment: can't you make the comparator passed to the treeset consistent with equals? I.e. make it return 0 only if the elements are equal as per the equals method

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Unfortunately, no. In fact, the library I am using creates new instances (different from an `equals` point of view) for objects that are in reality equal (from my point of view).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching and reading correctly the documentation about `TreeSet`, it turns out that:

> Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an
>   explicit comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if it
>   is to correctly implement the Set interface. (See Comparableor
>   Comparator for a precise definition of consistent with equals.) This is
>   so because the Set interface is defined in terms of the equals
>   operation, but a TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons
>   using its compareTo (or compare) method, so two elements that are
>   deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal.
>   The behavior of a set is well-defined even if its ordering is
>   inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of
>   the Set interface.

Which means that the `TreeSet` used in the example cannot be used as a `Set`. Therefore, the easiest solution is to create a `HashSet` for the `removeAll`operations by replacing every:

```
set1.removeAll(set2);
```

by

```
set1.removeAll(new HashSet<>(set2));
```

Maybe not the best solution from a performance point of view but a working one.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

```
 AtomicReference a = new AtomicReference<>("A");
 AtomicReference a2 = new AtomicReference<>("A");
 System.out.println(a==a2);
```

your answer lies within.

if instead of `Object` you use a custom class and you Override equals method it will work as expected.

to get this to work

```
class AtomicString{
private AtomicReference<String> s;

public AtomicString(String s) {
    this.s = new AtomicReference<>(s);
}

@Override public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o)
        return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
        return false;
    AtomicString that = (AtomicString) o;
    return this.s.get().equals(that.getS().get());
}

public AtomicReference<String> getS() {
    return s;
}

@Override public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(s.get());
}
```

Comment: The thing is that I am relying on a final class from a libray and cannot adapt it easily. But I updated my question to add some information. Anyway, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem really is the inconsistent "equality" logic. Both `TreeSet` and `HashSet` inherit `AbstractSet#removeAll`, which iterates over the smaller set, therefore using that set's object comparison. As it turns out, "equality" logic can be overridden using a `TreeSet`.

This is a problem that you can avoid by choosing one of the two `Set` implementations. If you choose `TreeSet`, then you must also use the same comparator.

You can't really use `HashSet` in this case because `AtomicReference` doesn't have an implementation of `equals`/`hashCode` that would work for you. So your only practical choice is to use `TreeSet`:

```
Comparator<Object> comparator = (a, b) -> a.toString().compareTo(b.toString());
final Set<Object> set1 = new TreeSet<>(comparator);
final Set<Object> set2 = new TreeSet<>(comparator);
```

This will break your current tests, but because elements are now being removed as they should (according to your comparator's logic).

Comment: I updated my question to add some information and try to be as precise as possible. You are right but unfortunately, I must mix different kind of `sets`.